# Conditions with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I have a little question. I don't find the way to get what I want.
I have an array. I create the variable "Tri_1" in order to get only the rows which respect my condition.

But I want to get also the rows from an other column which take account the previous condition in order to draw a graphic (g0-r0) in x and g0 in y. So just get rows in the column 'g0' where Tri_1 works.

```
Tri_1 = tbdata[((tbdata['g0-r0']) < 0.8) & (-0.4 < (tbdata['g0-r0']))]  # Ne garder que les -0.4 < (g-r)0 < 0.8

print tbdata[(tbdata['g0'], Tri_1)]
```

I don't know how I can do that ..

My input file looks like that :

```
ID          RA        DEC     NDET DEPTHFLAG SEPINDX [65] SEPFINDX [65]   U   UERR    G       GERR      R       RERR      I       IERR       Z       ZERR      CHI      SHARP   FLAG PROB    EBV   g0   r0   i0   z0   X   Y   g0-r0
------------- ---------- ---------- ---- --------- ------------ ------------- ----- ---- ------- --------- ------- --------- ------- ---------- ------- ---------- -------- --------- ---- ---- --------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------- --------
Field169.1255 184.766833 -30.472462   17         3   1254 .. -1    1254 .. -1 99.99 9.99 21.4875 0.0100426 20.0497 0.0070361 18.9002 0.00376412 18.4352 0.00425852 0.911594 -0.212171   -1 0.87 0.0709362 21.257831573486328, 19.895366668701172, 18.787057876586914, 18.348880767822266, -0.23369831258206375, 0.98211750000000109, 1.3624649047851562
```

The reason is that I want to plot g0 in function of (g0-r0). But, if I make :

```
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(Tri_1, tbdata['g0'], '.')
plt.title('Diagramme Couleur-Magnitude étoiles bleues')
plt.xlabel('(g0-r0)')
plt.ylabel('g0')
plt.xlim(-1.5,2.5)
plt.ylim(14,28)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

It doesn't work because x and y have not the same dimensions. So I just want 'g0' corresponding to 'g0-r0'

Thank you !

UPDATE :

This is what I found up to now :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.table import Table
from astropy.table import Column
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    ###################################
    # Importation du fichier de champ #
    ###################################

filename = '/home/valentin/Desktop/Field169_combined_final_roughcal.fits_traite_traiteXY_traiteXY_final'

print 'Fichier en cours de traitement' + str(filename) + '\n'

# Ouverture du fichier à l'aide d'astropy
field = fits.open(filename)        

# Lecture des données fits 
tbdata = field[1].data            


    #######################################
    # Paramètres pour la carte de densité #
    #######################################

# Boite des étoiles bleues :
Blue_stars_X = tbdata[np.bitwise_and(tbdata['g0-r0'] > -0.5, tbdata['g0-r0'] < 0.8 )] # Ne garder que les -0.4 < (g-r)0 < 0.8
Blue_stars_Y = Blue_stars = Blue_stars_X[Blue_stars_X['g0'] < 23.5]

RA_Blue_stars = ?? # get values RA from previous conditions
DEC_Blue_stars = ?? # get values DEC from previous conditions

# Boite des étoiles très bleues :
Very_Blue_stars_X = tbdata[np.bitwise_and(tbdata['g0-r0'] > -0.5, tbdata['g0-r0'] < 0.2 )]
Very_Blue_stars_Y = Very_Blue_stars = Very_Blue_stars_X[Very_Blue_stars_X['g0'] < 23.5]



    #####################################
    # Traçage des différents graphiques #
    #####################################


fig1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(tbdata['g0-r0'], tbdata['g0'], 'r.', label=u'Etoiles du champ')
plt.plot(Blue_stars['g0-r0'], Blue_stars['g0'], 'b.', label =u'Etoiles bleues')
plt.plot(Very_Blue_stars['g0-r0'], Very_Blue_stars['g0'], 'k.', label =u'Etoiles très bleues')
plt.title('Diagramme Couleur-Magnitude')
plt.xlabel('(g0-r0)')
plt.ylabel('g0')
plt.xlim(-1.5,2.5)
plt.ylim(14,28)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
#fig.savefig('CMD.png')

print "Création du Diagramme"
```

Comment: You might consider setting up a minimal example with the inputs and outputs you want.

Comment: @Ami Tavory My question is edited ^^ Hopfully that's better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to include elements that satisfy a condition, let's say:

```
condition = (tbdata['g0-r0']) < 0.8) & (-0.4 < (tbdata['g0-r0'])
```

then you need to use the condition on both your axes so that you combine only elements for the same entry.

```
x_data = tbdata[condition]['g0-r0']
y_data = tbdata[condition]['g0']
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, '.')
```

or with your condition you only need to change the `plot` line:

```
plt.plot(Tri_1['g0-r0'], Tri_1['g0'], '.')
```

## For your case:

```
# Setup the condition:
condition1 = np.bitwise_and(tbdata['g0-r0'] > -0.5, tbdata['g0-r0'] < 0.8 )
# Combine it with the g0 condition
condition_final = np.bitwise_and(Blue_stars_X['g0'] < 23.5, condition1)
# Get all rows where the condition is true:
Blue_stars = tbdata[condition_final]

RA_Blue_stars = Blue_stars['RA']
DEC_Blue_stars = Blue_stars['DEC']
```

To keep it clean I don't care about the very blues at the moment, just use something similar to the above.

And then plot it:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(tbdata['g0-r0'], tbdata['g0'], 'r.', label=u'Etoiles du champ')
plt.plot(Blue_stars['g0-r0'], Blue_stars['g0'], 'b.', label =u'Etoiles bleues')
plt.title('Diagramme Couleur-Magnitude')
plt.xlabel('(g0-r0)')
plt.ylabel('g0')
plt.xlim(-1.5,2.5)
plt.ylim(14,28)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
#fig.savefig('CMD.png')
```

Comment: Yes, i was working on the problem up to now, and I found something similar ! I update my question with what I found, but I juste have one more little problem

Comment: I know that what i'm searching about RA and DEC is similar, but I didn't find the request exactly.

Comment: Don't try to do everything at once, try to get one working and then adapt it for a second input and check if it still works, your question code is so crowded that it is hard to keep track. Use functions or classes and make your code modular where everything works (use unittests!) and if you want to expand it make another function and get that to work with small exemplaric inputs and then try hitting it with your real big data. I've updated the answer nevertheless. But for your next questions: Try to keep it smaller and specific (and ask a new question for follow-up questions)

Comment: I take account your answer ! Thank you so much for it and your update ! I was working on my script again and, by luck, I find the same thing than you (very similar anyway, but maybe less simple ..)